# Unterminated string literal in JSON string with values from SQLServer with HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server, ajax, json

I have been trying to solve a 'Unterminated string literal error' which I get in Firebug when I select 'Breast' from the dropdown on this page - http://wftp.whclpreview.com/search.html and hit on the submit button. The error points to the quotes that I have highlighted in bold -

SpecialGroups":"a","NationalAudits":"na","SpecialInterests":**"**

Basically this error is the result of an $.ajax call on a ASP.NET function that returns data from a SQLServer database (containg a field called SpecialInterests) in JSON format. The database is attached to an admin that alows users to format text via a CKEDITOR plugin.

If the text is simple then all is ok but if it contains any HTML tags or line breaks then I get the above error.

Any suggestions most welcome, thanks.

Comment: Do you have any control over the server side?

Comment: Yes I do the function that accepts a datatable as a paramemeter and outputs valid JSON is the folowing -

Comment: http://wftp.whclpreview.com/DATATABLE-JSON.txt

Comment: There's probably an error there .. why don't you use a C# library for JSON stringification?  I'm sure there's a ton of them, and probably even one in the standard library

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AJAX, you can pass an **Object Literal** or build the querystring with de data: e.g.

```js
 //if the variable contains HTML string,
 //ensure to encode it before sending the request
 var note = "  <strong>Important:</strong><br/> Additional notes. ";
 note = encodeHtml(note);

 //Object Literal
 var params = { "date": date, "expiry": expiry, "priority": priority, "note": note };

 //Query string to append to the url
 var paramsUrl = buildUrlParams(params).join("&");

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "myservice/client",

    //ugly way
    //data: "date="+date+"&expiry="+expiry+"&priority="+priority+"&note="+note,

    //passing data as Literal Object        
    data: params,

    //passing data as querystring
    //data: paramsUrl,

    success: function(data){ alert(data); }
  });
```

---

```js
  //Creates an array of parameters to build an URL querystring
  //@obj: Object to build the array of parameters
  function buildUrlParams(obj) {
      return $.map(obj, function(value, key) {
          return key + "=" + value;
      });
  }
```

---

```js
  //Encodes the HMTL to their respective HTML entities
  //@text: the HTML string to encode
  function encodeHtml(text) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    if ("innerText" in div) div.innerText = text;
    else div.textContent = text;
    return div.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, "");
  }
```

Comment: Based on Explosion Pills suggestion, I decided to use JSON.NET. instead of the custom function, this worked a treat. Many thanks to both of you!